# Binomial identities of $nx$ and $n(n-1)x^2 +nx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I have just started learned some basic things about the binomial theorem, for fun.

I have seen that $1=\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r} x^r (1-x)^{n-r}$, and I would like to use this fact to prove that:

$nx =\sum_{r=0}^{n} r{n \choose r} x^r (1-x)^{n-r}$

and

$n(n-1)x^2 + nx =\sum_{r=0}^{n} r^2{n \choose r} x^r (1-x)^{n-r}$

What sort of techniques should I be using here? All I have learned in my reference so far is the binomial theorem, basic applications, examples, corollaries, and then that formula for $1$.

I attempted induction, substitution, differentiation, and haven't quite come up with the right answer yet.

Comment: Hint: differentiate $\displaystyle(x+y)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nrx^ry^{n-r}$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: A useful fact is that $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: Ok, using the hint I got the first one pretty easily. That's neat. How does the second one work?

Comment: @JohnnyApple, differentiate twice.